Android Automotive has no audio in Cuttlefish AVD
I am running an Android Automotive instance on AWS Graviton using AWS CloudFormation. I noticed that there is no sound no matter what I do. Looking at logcat, I see this:
10-29 04:25:28.328  7171  7171 D CAR.AUDIO.KS: Starting device address audio
10-29 04:25:28.328  7171  7171 I CAR.AUDIO.KS.AudioPlayer: Asking for focus for usage 1
10-29 04:25:28.329   584  2726 I MediaFocusControl: requestAudioFocus() from uid/pid 1010028/7171 AA=USAGE_MEDIA/CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN clientId=android.media.AudioManager@86fa479com.google.android.car.kitchensink.audio.AudioPlayer$1@a3c15be callingPack=com.google.android.car.kitchensink req=2 flags=0x0 sdk=32
10-29 04:25:28.329  1422  1422 W CAR.AUDIO: getZoneIdForUid userId 10 does not have a zone. Defaulting to PRIMARY_AUDIO_ZONE:0
10-29 04:25:28.330  1422  1422 I CarAudioFocus: Evaluating GAIN_TRANSIENT request for client android.media.AudioManager@86fa479com.google.android.car.kitchensink.audio.AudioPlayer$1@a3c15be with usage USAGE_MEDIA
10-29 04:25:28.330  1422  1422 I CarAudioFocus: Scanning focus holders...
10-29 04:25:28.330  1422  1422 I CarAudioFocus: Scanning those who've already lost focus...
10-29 04:25:28.330  1422  1422 I CarAudioFocus: AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED
10-29 04:25:28.330  1422  1422 I CarAudioFocus: onAudioFocusRequest for client android.media.AudioManager@86fa479com.google.android.car.kitchensink.audio.AudioPlayer$1@a3c15be with gain type GAIN_TRANSIENT resulted in REQUEST_GRANTED
10-29 04:25:28.330  7171  7171 I CAR.AUDIO.KS.AudioPlayer: MediaPlayer got focus for usage 1
10-29 04:25:28.330  7171  7171 I CAR.AUDIO.KS.AudioPlayer: doStart audio
10-29 04:25:28.339  7171  7171 D CAR.AUDIO.KS.AudioPlayer: doStart preferred device address: Speaker
10-29 04:25:28.343   501  7230 D CCodecConfig: read media type: audio/mpeg
10-29 04:25:28.345   501  7230 D CCodecConfig:   string input.media-type.value = "audio/mpeg"
10-29 04:25:28.345   501  7230 D CCodecConfig:   string output.media-type.value = "audio/raw"
10-29 04:25:28.347   501  7230 D CCodec  :   string mime = "audio/mpeg"
10-29 04:25:28.347   501  7230 D CCodec  :   string mime = "audio/raw"
10-29 04:25:28.356  2628  2628 W AudioFlinger: createTrack_l(): mismatch between requested flags (00000008) and output flags (00000002)
10-29 04:25:28.356  2628  2628 D AudioFlinger: Client defaulted notificationFrames to 11224 for frameCount 22448
10-29 04:25:28.356  2628  2628 D AF::TrackHandle: OpPlayAudio: track:58 usage:1 not muted
10-29 04:25:28.358  2628  2661 E AudioFlinger: no wake lock to update, but system ready!
10-29 04:25:28.359  2627  2641 E android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/stream_out.cpp:updateSourceMetadata:377 failure: Result::NOT_SUPPORTED
10-29 04:25:28.359   501  7228 D AudioTrack: getTimestamp_l(9): device stall time corrected using current time 9964178094107
10-29 04:25:28.382  2627  2641 E android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/stream_out.cpp:updateSourceMetadata:377 failure: Result::NOT_SUPPORTED
10-29 04:25:28.382  2628  2661 D AudioFlinger: mixer(0xb40000700bf62a60) throttle end: throttle time(110)
10-29 04:25:28.641  2628  2661 D AudioFlinger: mixer(0xb40000700bf62a60) throttle end: throttle time(231)
10-29 04:25:28.900  2628  2661 D AudioFlinger: mixer(0xb40000700bf62a60) throttle end: throttle time(230)
10-29 04:25:29.147   501  7228 W NuPlayerRenderer: AudioSink stuck. ARE YOU CONNECTED TO AUDIO OUT? Switching to system clock.
10-29 04:25:29.159  2628  2661 D AudioFlinger: mixer(0xb40000700bf62a60) throttle end: throttle time(231)
10-29 04:25:29.418  2628  2661 D AudioFlinger: mixer(0xb40000700bf62a60) throttle end: throttle time(231)
10-29 04:25:29.675  2628  2661 D AudioFlinger: mixer(0xb40000700bf62a60) throttle end: throttle time(231)
10-29 04:25:29.933  2628  2661 D AudioFlinger: mixer(0xb40000700bf62a60) throttle end: throttle time(231)
10-29 04:25:30.214  2628  2661 D AudioFlinger: mixer(0xb40000700bf62a60) throttle end: throttle time(253)
10-29 04:25:30.472  2628  2661 D AudioFlinger: mixer(0xb40000700bf62a60) throttle end: throttle time(231)
10-29 04:25:30.729  2628  2661 D AudioFlinger: mixer(0xb40000700bf62a60) throttle end: throttle time(231)
10-29 04:25:30.987  2628  2661 D AudioFlinger: mixer(0xb40000700bf62a60) throttle end: throttle time(231)
10-29 04:25:31.245  2628  2661 D AudioFlinger: mixer(0xb40000700bf62a60) throttle end: throttle time(231)
10-29 04:25:31.342  7171  7171 I CAR.AUDIO.KS.AudioPlayer: stop
10-29 04:25:31.347  2627  2641 E android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/stream_out.cpp:updateSourceMetadata:377 failure: Result::NOT_SUPPORTED
10-29 04:25:31.356   584  1366 I MediaFocusControl: abandonAudioFocus() from uid/pid 1010028/7171 clientId=android.media.AudioManager@86fa479com.google.android.car.kitchensink.audio.AudioPlayer$1@a3c15be
10-29 04:25:31.357  1422  1422 W CAR.AUDIO: getZoneIdForUid userId 10 does not have a zone. Defaulting to PRIMARY_AUDIO_ZONE:0
10-29 04:25:31.357  1422  1422 I CarAudioFocus: onAudioFocusAbandon for client android.media.AudioManager@86fa479com.google.android.car.kitchensink.audio.AudioPlayer$1@a3c15be
10-29 04:25:31.357  1422  1422 I CarAudioFocus: removeFocusEntry android.media.AudioManager@86fa479com.google.android.car.kitchensink.audio.AudioPlayer$1@a3c15be

What exactly is the issue here, and how can I find out more?
I feel very stuck.. Thanks!

You're trying to decode an audio/mpeg file and sound it to the speaker which supports audio/raw. This translation is not automatically supported by the emulator. Try playing instead a file which would use the same source and target codecs like raw PCM wav file, and see what happens
